# EL how to display an array of String items with one statement

Tags: java, arrays, jsf, datatable, el

I have a string array property `'displayWeekend'` in a bean.

```
String[] displayWeekend; //property in a object.
```

I want to display the collection of these objects in a DataTable column.

Example:`"#{rowData.displayWeekend}"`

This returns the array memory location `[Ljava.lang.String;@2cb62cb6]`

I do not want to pick specific elements, I want to display all elements with one expression language statement.

Comment: _"I want to display all elements with one expression language statement."_ why in one EL statement? Using a `ui:repeat` gives much greater control

Answer (score 3):

Calling `#{rowData.displayWeekend}` will call the method `toString()` on the displayWeekend object

You need to override it, or simply use a method to display each elements like : `Arrays.toString(displayWeekend)`